# What is the Bootstrap card-block class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I don't see the class `card-block` mentioned in the reference documentation, but I have seen this class used in a few examples. This is the officially reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

And this is an example where the class is used:

https://www.codeply.com/go/pVsGQZVVtG/bootstrap-4-no-gutters-(spacing)

I've seen cards used but what is this `card-block` class?

**Example:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        normal
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        normal
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        normal
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `card-block` class was used on an **Alpha Release** version of **Bootstrap 4** and doesn't exists on the current release. You can read the documentation of that class on the link: [card-block on v4-Alpha](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#blocks). There says that:

> The building block of a card is the `.card-block`. Use it whenever you need a padded section within a card.

Like I already mention, this class do not exist on the currently **v4.1.3 release** or another superior version. You can check with the browser inspector tool on the next example and see that there is no **CSS** style related to the `card-block` class but there exists **CSS** style related to, like an example, the officially documented `card-header` or `card-body` classes.

Link to official documentation about `cards`: [Bootstrap Cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
    card-block
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      card-header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      card-body
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: so it is became card-body?

Comment: @netalex Yes, you can use `card-body` to get a padded section within a `card`.